# Mac webcam as a device file

Tags: mac, webcam

I'm messing around with wine on Mac, and it went pretty well for a while (I even helped someone port his app to Mac). Recently, I started playing with webcam, and this time I run into a problem. /dev directory is not shown in finder, which is totally fine and understandable considering this is what MacOS is like. I used command to cd into it, and I cannot find /dev/video0 directory. Is it located in another weird directory or it just doesn't exist? If it doesn't, it there anyway of creating one myself?